# Не отображается повторно drop down menu

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, bootstrap

Возникла проблема при использовании bootstrap шаблона.
Есть navbar на котором стоит drop down menu, при первом нажатии оно отображается, а при следующих - нет. В чём может быть проблема? Для работы использую Laravel, файл app.js гружу через defer для работы списка, хотя он возможно не причём.[image: Drop down menu]

```
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      @guest
          <li><a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('login') }}">{{ __('Login') }}</a></li>
          <li><a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('register') }}">{{ __('Register') }}</a></li>
      @else
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a id="navbarDropdown" style="color: white;" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" v-pre>
                  {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
              </a>

              <div class="dropdown-menu" style="right: 0; left: auto;" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                  <a class="dropdown-item text-right" href="{{ route('users.editprofile') }}">
                      {{ __('Edit Profile') }}
                  </a>

                  <a class="dropdown-item text-right" href="{{ route('cards.createcard') }}">
                      {{ __('Add card') }}
                  </a>
                  <hr>
                  <a class="dropdown-item text-right" href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                     onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                   document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                      {{ __('Logout') }}
                  </a>

                  <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                      @csrf
                  </form>
              </div>
          </li>
      @endguest
  </ul>
```

Comment: Какие ошибки выдает консоль браузера?

Comment: Никаких, файл app.js грузит спокойно через defer, как и указано в файле index.blade.php.

Comment: Даже после первого нажатия, никаких ошибок в консоли не возникает? В целом, похоже на некорректно работающий либо конфликтующий скрипт открытия/закрытия меню

Comment: Да ошибок нет при первом нажатии и при последующих, тогда видимо в app.js проблема (вряд ли) или в самом шаблоне. Думаю .css файл тут также ни причём

Comment: Сложно угадать без реального кода. Можете попробовать воссоздать на jsfiddle, например. Уже получится предметный разговор

Comment: А GitHub подойдет?

Comment: На GitHub просто у меня есть уже реп проекта.

Comment: Вряд-ли кому то будет удобно разворачивать проект у себя с Гитхаба. Суть в том, что бы быстро посмотреть живой вариант, увидеть работу

Comment: Именно в index.blade.php есть это меню, но чтобы оно выпадало есть app.js, думаете что именно его нужно кидать? Он там не маленький.

Comment: Решил проблему, у меня грузились скрипты: jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js, tether.min.js, bootstrap.min.js через defer с интернет ресурсов. Нужно defer оставить только для app.js в моём проекте.

Comment: Блин после нескольких кликов всё равно перестаёт отображаться. В чём проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему, убрав выпадающий список (заменил на ссылки в самом баре), видимо сам шаблон не поддерживает нормально этот drop down ведь загружал скрипты с jquery и другие с оф. сайта bootstrap. Рандомность отображения этого меню зашкаливает, после обновления он кликабелен 3 раза, потом 5, потом 6 и так далее.